# Composer view seem to not respond at all

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I created 3 composer views previously and they all work properly, but than I created andother one, which doesn't seem to work. I've been trying to get it work for 3 days and it doesn't seem to be something related with my code. I will drop pieceof it here, but I still don't think it's the code.

Provider EvenComposerProvider:

```
public function register(){
    $this->composeEven();
}
public function composeEven(){
    view()->composer('includes.aklinkosesi', 'App\Http\Composers\EvenComposer');
}
```

Composer EvenComposer:

```
class EvenComposer{
   public function compose(View $view){
      $view->with('evens', Even::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10));
   }
}
```

And than I uncluded the provider inside `app.php`

```
App\Providers\EvenComposerProvider::class
```

When I try to loop through `$evens` with the foreach, it throws the error:

> Undefined variable: evens

My rough guess will be that, Laravel does not compile `app.php`

Comment: Btw I asked this question previously but nobody had interest in helping, so If you can't answer than please vote-up so I might get a better chance of solving it

Comment: I placed bounty on the previous question and updated it for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `view()->composer()` in the `boot` method rather than the `register` method.

You have no guarantee of the services you depend on being available in `register`, that's what `boot` is for.

Comment: I see, I will try and respond back

Comment: Nope It still doesn't work